# Pandas read excel file and fill missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiy4Paqm5TmAhUZRBUIHWXaA9UQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nist.gov%2Fdocument-3764&usg=AOvVaw3h6tZ6GoIxe_kKqUrPnp9t) excel file into Pandas as follows:

```
xlsnist = pd.ExcelFile(path+'framework-for-improving-critical-infrastructure-cybersecurity-core.xlsx')

df3 = pd.read_excel(xlsnist, "CSF Core")
```

The screenshot below shows that this file has merged cells.  I want to fill the empty rows with the relevant values for Function, Category, Subcategory.  For example the NaN cells of Function should have "IDENTIFY (ID)" until it changes to "PROTECT (PR)" at row 82.  I want to do this for all columns so there are no "NaN" values but I'm not sure how to do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try playing with `df3['col_name'].fillna(method='ffill')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'framework-for-improving-critical-infrastructure-cybersecurity-core.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df.ffill()
```

Result:

[image]